# Why do I lose whether or not a property is optional in this Mapped Type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, mapped-types

I have a mapped type `Minus<A,B>` for creating a type with all the properties on A except those that are also on B which is defined as follows:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];

/**
 * Type T without any of the properties on U.
 */
export type Minus<T, U> = {[P in Diff<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[P]};
```

For example, if I have two interfaces, `A`

```
interface A {
    thing1: string;
    thing2: number;
}
```

and `B`

```
interface B {
    thing1: string;
}
```

then `Minus<A, B>` should result in a type equivalent to

```
interface C {
    thing2: number;
}
```

This works well until I have optional types on A, as these are lost somewhere along the way.

Replacing `A` with

```
interface A {
    thing1: string;
    thing2?: number;
}
```

will result in an type that looks like

```
interface C {
    thing2: number;
}
```

instead of the desired

```
interface C {
    thing2?: number;    
}
```

Interestingly, the behavior for a `Readonly<T>` does seem to retain whether or not properties are optional; Readonly will produce a type equivalent to

```
interface ReadonlyA {
    readonly thing1: string;
    readonly thing2?: number;
}
```

So I suspect that this has something to do with my Diff type.

Does anyone have a solution that will retain whether properties are optional or not on `A`?

Comment: maybe this ? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183 last message from 23rf Nov

Comment: Hahaha that's actually where I got my original minus definition from. Should've read all the way to the bottom. Cheers man :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to redefine `Minus<A, B>` to be

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];

/**
 * Type T without any of the properties on U.
 */
export type Minus<T, U> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, keyof U>>;
```

Which will correctly retain optional types.

Credit to [Daniel Khoroshko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4598587/daniel-khoroshko) for pointing me in the right